# OData and inserting (AddLink) many-to-many relationships

Tags: wpf, odata, wcf-data-services

Ok guys, this is driving me nuts. I got the following (odata) entity which represents a page structure in which every page can have any children and any parents. (basically a graph in which all nodes could be connected). In the database it's represented by a many-to-many relationship with two tables `Page <-> PagePage <-> Page`.

[image: Page Entity]

The problem is, I'm just not able to insert a new entity including a relation. The last thing I tried was:

```
    Page page = new Page()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Title = "New Page",
        Created = DateTime.Now,
        LastChanged = DateTime.Now,
        IsRedirected = false,
        Position = 0,
        Html = "Add your HTML here.",
        Parent = { parent }
    };

    this.Context.AddToPages(page);
    this.Context.AddLink(parent, "Children", page);
    parent.Children.Add(page);
    this.Context.SaveChanges();
```

I can't think of anything else to try. Has anyone cracked this one?

**Edit 1**: Here's a picture from the database diagram:
[image: db diagram]

**Edit 2**: Exception Details:

```
System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException was unhandled
  Message=An error occurred while processing this request.
  Source=System.Data.Services.Client
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.HandleBatchResponse()
       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.EndRequest()
       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
       at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges()
       at PortfolioManagementConsole.Models.PageViewModel.SaveChanges(Object parameter) in C:\Users\Daniel\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PortfolioManagementService\PortfolioManagementConsole\Models\PageViewModel.cs:line 59
       at PortfolioManagementConsole.Common.RelayCommand.Execute(Object parameter) in C:\Users\Daniel\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PortfolioManagementService\PortfolioManagementConsole\Common\RelayCommand.cs:line 52
       at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
       at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadButton.OnClick() in c:\Builds\WPF_Scrum\Release_WPF\Sources\Development\Core\Controls\Buttons\RadButton.cs:line 348
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at PortfolioManagementConsole.App.Main() in C:\Users\Daniel\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PortfolioManagementService\PortfolioManagementConsole\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException
       Message=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code></code>
  <message xml:lang="de-CH">An error occurred while processing this request.</message>
</error>
       Source=System.Data.Services.Client
       StatusCode=500
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.<HandleBatchResponse>d__1e.MoveNext()
       InnerException:
```

Comment: What error do you get? Or is it just that the entity doesn't seem to be inserted?

Comment: There's a DataServiceRequestException on the context.SaveChanges() method.

Comment: And the message of the exception?

Comment: Well that's the problem, it's just a "An error occurred while processing this request.". The Stack Trace gives me a "System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.HandleBatchResponse()" and the inner exception gives a "Status Code 500", the same Message and the "TargetSite {Boolean MoveNext()}"

Comment: Okay, that's the error you receive on the client. Is the server's code under your control? Can you look there for why it returned this error?

Comment: Please take a look at this how to enable more descriptive error messages http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx.

Comment: I got exactly the same exception, for me it was the size which exceed the default maximum. ( http://malvinly.com/2011/05/09/wcf-data-services-and-maxreceivedmessagesize/ )

In all case, you should check what error gives you the WCF logging

Answer (score 0):

Your WCF Data Services server is not returning detailed error messages and that's not helping you nail down the exact error message returned from the server. Follow these instructions to enable verbose error messages from the server : 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx .
After you've enabled this , you should be able to see the error message being thrown by the server.

From looking at your model, you need another link from the child back to the parent.
Add this line to the code right before SaveChanges :

this.Context.SetLink(page, "Parent", parent);

To help understand this better, here are some links on my blog where I detail how one works with associations using the WCF Data Services client :

1 to many associations

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/10/23/working-with-associations-in-ado-net-data-services-part-2.aspx

1 to 1 associations

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/07/02/working-with-relations-in-ado-net-data-services-beta-1.aspx